# JQuery access some JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've been working on this for like an hour now, but can't seem to figure it out.

The JSON response:

```
{"lastDate":"2013-11-22 00:00:35",
"lastId":"42460",
"response":[
{
"class":"rowgreen",
"id":"42460","date":"22 November 2013, 00:00:35\\u0026nbsp;",
"player":"\\u003Ca href=\\u0027logpersonal.php?playerName=skiwi2\\u0027\\u003Eskiwi2\\u003C\/a\\u003E\\u0026nbsp;",
"target":"\\u003Ca href=\\u0027logpersonal.php?playerName=UnholiestElite\\u0027\\u003EUnholiestElite\\u003C\/a\\u003E\\u0026nbsp;",
"weapon":"M1014 (\\u003Cb\\u003EHeadshot\\u003C\/b\\u003E)\\u0026nbsp;",
"server":"Test\\u0026nbsp;"
}
]}
```

This seems to be correct, now the jquery:

```
function longPolling() {
    if (!longPollingAllowed) {
        return;
    }
    console.log("Long polling started.");
    $.ajax({
        url: "logpersonal_ajax.php",
        data: {
            serverId: serverId,
            playerName: playerName,
            lastDate: lastDate,
            lastId: lastId
        },
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function() {
            longPollingBusy = true;
        },
        success: function(json) {
            console.log("success");
            $(json).each(function() {
                console.log("this.lastDate = " + this.lastDate);
                console.log("this.lastId = " + this.lastId)
                console.log("this.response = " + this.response);
                console.log(this.response);
                this.lastDate = this.lastDate;
                this.lastId = this.lastId;
                if (this.response != "") {
                    this.response.each(new function() {
                        console.log(this);
                        var clazz = this.class;
                        console.log("clazz = " + clazz);
                        var id = this.id;
                        var date = this.date;
                        var player = this.player;
                        var target = this.target;
                        var weapon = this.weapon;
                        var server = this.server;
                        var string = "\t\t\t<tr class='" + clazz + "' id='" + id + "'><td>" + date + "</td><td>" + player + "</td><td>" + target + "</td><td>" + weapon + "</td><td>" + server + "</td></tr>\n";
                        console.log("string = " + string);
                        $(string).insertBefore($("#list tr.header").next());               
                    });
                }
            });
            if (lastDate != "" && lastId != "") {
                //longPolling(serverId, playerName, lastDate);
            }
            longPollingBusy = false;
        },
        error: function(json, message) {
            console.log("fail: " + message);
            longPollingBusy = false;
        }
    });    
}
```

The `console.log("this.lastDate = " + this.lastDate);` works, so does the one for `this.lastId`. `this.response` also works and nicely shows an array starting with index `0` and when expanded it you can see all elements in the developer view.

Now comes the part I cannot seem to understand: At the `foreach` over `this.response` it does not print anything useful (except Prototype skeleton) for `this`.

How can I access the values?

Comment: When you say *"foreach"*, are you referencing this line? `this.response.each(new function() {` it probably should be `forEach`. Once that's changed to a `forEach`, you would need to use the parameters of the callback rather than `this` to access the array values.

Comment: `this.response.each` should not even work since arrays don't have an `each` method. Also, `new function() {...}` is certainly wrong. This would pass an *instance* (i.e. an object) of the function to `.each`. I'd also suggest that you be consistent: Either use jQuery methods or use native JS methods.

Comment: Why are you using an iterator here `$(json).each(function() {`?  The root element is not an array. Are you really trying to iterate over the returned object's properties?  It doesn't seem so as you are then trying to use things like `this.lastId`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.response.each(new function() {
```

This line is wrong. It should be:

```
this.response.forEach(function() {
```

P.S. I suggest doing `$.each(json, function(){` instead of `$(json).each(function() {`.